# How to write a INSERT query while omitting some records in a Transaction in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have written a SQL insert statement within a Transaction. (It is quite big)
When my transaction runs in a stored procedure, at insert phase, for a **NOT NULL Column** due to some backend issues, that particular column has been tried to fill up with **NULL** values. So, the whole transaction is getting ROllBACK. The disadvantage I see here is, This SP, handling thousand of INSERT queries, I do not want to skip other insert queries due to few NULL cases.

Is there a way I can add a condition to skip those NULL cases?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_populate]   
AS 

BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
----
---
...
    INSERT  INTO [dbo].[testTable]
                  ( .. ,
                   .. ,
                      .. ,
                      [AId] ,
                     ...,
                    )
SELECT(..,..,[AId], ...) from tableA

-------
       COMMIT TRANSACTION

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ....
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            ..
        END CATCH
```

Comment: `... where aid is not null`??

Comment: Couldn't you just add NULL check to your SELECT statement? SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE column IS NOT NULL?

Comment: @juergend yes, in some cases AId is NULL

Comment: @Heinrich Oh..looks simple, ill try that solution :)